# Insert blank page in pdf file using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

The below excel VBA code helps in opening pdf file named "VA". How to insert blank page in the beginning of the pdf file? I need to water mark blank with with data.

```
vAccol = "VA"
Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myShell.Run FolderName & "\" & vAccol & ".PDF"
```

Comment: you'll need Adobe Acrobat Pro (i think latest version is called something else) if you want to directly insert blank page into PDF from Excel. There are other ways to do it though.

Comment: I user versioin XI, I need help with code in inserting a blank page in each document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add blank page at beginning of pdf file using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46427917/add-blank-page-at-beginning-of-pdf-file-using-vba)